# spaCy lemmatization (via .lemma_) is returning only empty strings

Tags: python, spacy

I cannot get spaCy lemmatization to work, it always returns empty strings.

```
import spacy  
from spacy.lang.en import English

nlp = English()  
text = "I went to the bank today for checking my bank balance."  
doc = nlp(text)
```

This returns just empty strings:

```
for token in doc:  
    print(token.lemma_)
```

System info:

```
Windows 10 Pro 64bits
Python 3.8.8
spacy                         3.0.6
spacy-legacy                  3.0.5
```

Am I doing something wrong? I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lemma data is pretty large, so it's not included in the core spaCy install. You need to install an English model or the lookups data. You can download the small model like this:

```
spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Then load the model.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

doc = nlp("cheeses")
print(doc[0].lemma_) # "cheese"
```

That should do it.